# Django-stripe Integration give 403 Forbidden after payment

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Below is my setup of stripe in Django ,

view.py

```
def charge(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' :
      resp = " Payment Successful !"
      try:
        token = request.POST['stripeToken']
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=2000, # amount in cents, again
            currency="usd",
            source=token,
            description="Example charge"
        )  
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Success Logger !'
      except stripe.error.CardError as e:
        resp = str(e)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^sign_in$', views.sign_in, name='sign_in'),
    url(r'^sign_out$', views.sign_out, name='sign_out'),
    url(r'^register$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^edit$', views.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^charge$', views.charge, name='charge'),

    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

user.html

```
{% extends "page.html" %}
{% block main %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 columns">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>Welcome {{ user.name }}.</p>
      <p>Your credit card ends with {{ user.last_4_digits }} (<a href="{% url edit %}">change</a>)</p>
      <form action="/charge" method="POST" id="payment_form">
          <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="pk_test_xFLF8rLaykv0tiGXFkhMj5XF"
            data-amount="2000"
            data-name="Vevanesca"
            data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
            data-image="/128x128.png"
            data-locale="auto">
          </script>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm using the default checkout.js provided by stripe . Once the payment overlay pops up, I type in the test details . Next thing, after a few second it redirects to `/charge` with an `Error 403 Forbidden CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`.

How can I resolve this ? I just want to setup a simple test gateway using stripe .

Comment: You don't have `{% csrf_token %}` inside your form.  Have you tried using that?

Comment: cant I bypass it ? also adding it doesnt help .

Comment: You can remove `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` from the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` entry in `settings.py`.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/ for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick and dirty fix, just remove `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` from the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` entry in `settings.py`.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/ for more info.

Comment: You shouldn't do this, as it removes CSRF from all views, including your own forms. Instead, just put the `@csrf_exempt` decorator around the charge view.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Do not just blindly remove CSRF from your project!

Answer (score 2):

Please add @csrf_exempt at the top of the view or try to add / at the end of the calling url.

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def view(request):
        return httpresponse('done')
```